# Can't link my css file to header partial properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add my CSS file to my header partial

This is my link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/app.css">
```

my directory:

```
project
   models
   node_modules
   public
      stylesheets
         app.css
   views
      partials
         header.js
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: What doctype are you using? HTML5 or something else? Also, where is the file stored where you are including the HTML to call that CSS file?

Comment: can you share your sample code of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: html5, the file im using this link in is the header.js

Comment: A CSS file cannot be included in a JS file. You must include the CSS file in a HTML file.

Comment: My first guess is that `stylesheets/app.css` should be `/stylesheets/app.css`.  `project/public` is probably your document root and routing might be causing the browser to look in the wrong place for your CSS.  can you navigate to `http://yourdomain.whatever/stylesheets/app.css`?

Comment: The reason everyone is asking for the HTML location is because independently of which path you use on your `.js`, when your code appends this `<link>` tag on an HTML file, the path will be processed from the HTML file itself. So your `.js` file location won't make a difference. @JosephMarikle is suggesting that your path comes from the root instead of your current directory. I recommend taking a look at how HTML file paths work.

Answer (score 0):

A CSS file cannot be included in a JS file. You must include the CSS file in a HTML file.

Comment: one way it can be added is by dynamically creating an link element  and adding it to the head element.

Comment: Ronen, are you satisfied with this answer? If yes, please check it as accepted, otherwise please explain why not.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you are using Express, then include this in your main javascript file  (app.js/index.js/where ever your routes are):

```
//Use public dir:
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

2) Change your header partial from header.js to header.ejs. Make sure your link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/app.css">
```

is included here.

3) At the top of the desired "views" file, be sure to include:

```
<%- include("partials/header") %>
```